# Make a table of div with images and text

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

I did a div table with 3 image with text for each row, the problem is that I can't make all the div that contains text at the same size, how can I do that? I have to put this table at the centre of the screen, I did this with padding attribute, there is a more efficient way?

Comment: Please expand your question to more than two sentences. We need to see you code in the form of a [mcve] with details explaining what you're trying to accomplish in addition to what problems you're having and any errors. See [ask]

Comment: did you make a table? a table built with divs?

Answer (score 0):

> make all the div that contains text at the same size

add a class to the div's containing text and set the height and width in css like this:

HTML: `<div class="textDiv">texttexttext</div>`

CSS: `.textDiv {height: 150px; width: 150px;}`

> put this table at the centre of the screen

create a container for your divs (you probably already have one)
add a class to it like this:

HTML: `<div class="divContainer"`>

than set the margin to auto and a width if you need one:

CSS: `.divContainer {margin: auto; width: 50%;}`

Comment: thanks for help :) I hope there were a method with % for mobile usage too but I think there isn't :/ there is a vai to center my table of div automatically?